# Data structure for piecewise circular trajectory in plane

Tags: data-structures, geometry

I'm trying to design a data-structure to hold/express a piecewise circular trajectory in the Euclidian plane. The trajectory is constrained to be continuous and have finite curvature everywhere, and therefore the circular arcs meet tangentially.

Storing all the circle centers, radii, and touching points would allow for inspecting the geometry anywhere in O(1) but would require explicit enforcement of the continuity and curvature constraints due to data redundancy. In my view, this would make the code messy.

Storing only the circle touching points (which are waypoints along the curve) along with the curve's *initial* direction would be sufficient in principle, and avoid data redundancy, but then it would be necessary to do an O(n) calculation to inspect the geometry of arc n, since that arc depends on all the arcs preceding it in the trajectory.

I would like to avoid data redundancy, but I also don't want to make the cost of geometric inspection prohibitive.

Does anyone have any high-level idea/advice to share?

Comment: This looks pretty language agnostic as is.  I'm removing the C++ tag.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ninja'd ;)

Comment: @NeilButterworth Ok thanks, but was the 'design' tag also incorrect?

Comment: `design` is a pretty useless tag as it covers just about any problem, from GUI design to algorithm design, and  other things.

Comment: @NeilButterworth And data-structures design. Is the tag actually not supposed to exist then?

Comment: Lots of tags here are useless - they are very easy to create by people who haven't thought much about what they are doing. There might as well be a `programming` tag.

Comment: Could you show a picture of your trajectory? How is it built (so there might be native data description)? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: You should detail the queries you need to do. What do you mean by "inspecting the geometry" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust You're right. So far only `[x,y] = trajectory(s)` where `s` is distance traveled along trajectory.

Comment: Random or sequential access ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust random access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most efficient traversal of the trajectory, if I am right you need

- the ending curvilinear abscissas of every arc (cumulative),
- the radii,
- the starting angles,
- the coordinates of the centers,

so that for a given `s` you find the index of the arc, then the azimuth and the coordinates of the point. (Either incrementally for a sequence of points, or by dichotomy for a single point.) That takes five parameters per arc.

Only the cumulative abscissas are global, but you can't do without them for single-point accesses. You can drop the radii and starting angles and retrieve them for any arc from the difference of curvilinear abscissas and the limit angles (see below). This reduces to three parameters.

On the other hand, knowing just the coordinates of the centers and those of the starting and ending points is enough to recover the whole geometry, and this takes two parameters per arc.

The meeting point of two arcs is found on the line through the centers, and if you know one radius, the other follows. And the limit angle is given by the direction of the line. So for an incremental traversal, this non-redundant description can do.

[image]

---

For convenient computation, knowing s and the arc index, consider the vectors from the center to the centers of the adjoining arcs. Rotate them so that the first becomes horizontal. The components of the other will give you the amplitude angle. The fraction `(s - Si-1) / (Si - Si-1)` of the amplitude gives you the azimuth of the point, to which you apply the counter-rotation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd store items with the data required to get info for any point of that element. For example, an arc needs x, y, initial direction, radius, lenght (or end point, or angle difference or whatever you find easiest).

Because you need continuity (same x,y, same bearing, perhaps same curvature) between two ending points then a `node` with this properties is needed. Notice these properties are common to arcs and straights (a special arc identified by radius = 0). So you can treat a `node` the same as an `item`.

The trajectory should be calculated before any request. So you have all items-data in advance.

The container depends on how you request info.

If the trajectory can be somehow represented in a grid, then you better use a quad-tree.

I guess you must find the item from a `x,y` or `accumulated length` input. You will have to iterate through the container to find the element closest to the input data. Sorted data may help.

My choice is a simple vector with the consecutive elements, which happens to be sorted on accumulated trajectory length.

Finding by `x,y` on a x-sorted container (or a tree) is not so simple, due to some `x,y` may have perpendiculars to several items, consecutive or not, near or not, and you need to select the nearest one.